# Easy tool for drawing graphs and export as xml, json?

Tags: json, xml, graph

Do you know a tool/application that allows me to draw a directed graph (with drag and drop would be ideally) and than easily export it into an XML or JSON file?

I tried using [http://cmap.ihmc.us/](http://Cmap) but it exports the picture into an XML not the graph's content, which it makes it horrible to parse.

The main goal is to draw a graph and then somehow construct it in memory (in C++/Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gephi is a good free tool to create and export graphs:

https://gephi.org/

User made addons are available and allow you to export in multiple formats :

https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/json-exporter/

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.